# Get sum of a database field with where condition from multiple tables in PHP Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am having problem with fetching "sum" of a field from a table with multiple where conditions from multiple table in php MySQL.

For Example:

Table1:"Participant"

part_id |  name | total_part | work_id

1 |  Ravi | 2 | 102
2 |  Sam | 1 | 102
3 |  Mike | 3 | 101

Table2: "Workshop"

work_id |  Month | Year

101 |  March | 2
102 |  April | 1
103 |  May | 3

Form the above two table I want to select the sum of "total_part" from Participant with where condition of "work_id" and "Month" from workshop in single php mysql query.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We need something more than this to help you. Can you add some code to your question. The table structure, your query. And then people can help you with went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without having any context, it sounds like you're just looking for `SELECT SUM(column) FROM table WHERE [clause 1] AND [clause 2]`. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your Replay, but I want to check 'where' condition with two tables in database

Comment: Hmmm, so more like `select sum(p.total_part) from participant p join workshop w on (w.work_id = p.work_id) where [participant clause] and [workshop clause]`? If that is what you are looking for, mysql's join docs can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html. I'm sorry if this is not what you are looking for. I may just not be understanding what you are looking for, sorry.

Comment: Hi iavery this is what i'm looking for but how I will get the result

Comment: Are you asking how to run a SQL query using PHP? Or just what the exact syntax for the queries? I will update the query above with the appropriate aliases as well ... I have my Postgres hat on today :(

Comment: $pmpdp=mysql_query("select sum(p.total_part) AS value_sum from participant_details p join workshop_schedule w on (w.work_id = p.work_id) WHERE p.crmname = '$crm_id' and p.type='DP-0' and w.course='PMP'");

Comment: $pmpdps = mysql_result($pmpdp,0);          $sum = $pmpdps['value_sum'];           echo $sum;

Comment: I want to display total_part sum value

Comment: I believe mysql_result will return a cell's contents, not an array. Try `echo $pmpdps` before the last 2 lines. See http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-result.php